# How to apply declarativeNetRequest rules for extension page

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

My extension has a page: *chrome-extension://xxx/app.html* which contains an iframe that loads twitter.com

Since Twitter has X-Frame-Options: DENY header, I'd like to use `declarativeNetRequest` to remove the header.

But it seems that Chrome will not apply the rules for extension page itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?